# determine string "overlap" or "distance" in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, distance

I have two strings and I want to compare them.

*edit* To clarify I'd like to find the longest number of consecutive words the strings have in common.

For example the string: 
    "Eminent Domain for Modern : Daily MTG : Magic: The Gathering"
and 
"Building On A Budget: Eminent Domain For Modern"

would return 4, since both strings contain "eminent domain for modern" which contains 4 words.

however, if simply finding the number of words in common is faster then that method would be acceptable... I'm not sure the best way to do either...

Comment: You need to be more specific on what they should have in common. You say that you are looking for character strings they have in common, how long should they have to be? two letters? three? should it calculate the number of occurrences or the total number of consecutive letters in common? The question is to wide to answer without knowing what your measurement of "distance" is...

Comment: I would read the Apple Documentation on strings, There are many ways to search and compare strings.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035-SW1

Comment: Have a look at the [longest common substring problem on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a feeling it could be done in linear time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for details, but here's an approach.

Use the `NSString` method

```
– stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
```

to remove anything that isn't a space or letter. Then use the method

```
– componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
```

to convert the string into an `NSArray` where each element is a word. Do this for each of the two strings you wish to compare. Then loop through the elements of the one array and use the `NSArray` method

```
– containsObject:
```

to see if the second array also contains that word. Try that, and if you get stuck at a specific point, then post the code you have and ask again for help. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm doing... I was just hoping there would be a faster or more elegant way. Or maybe enven some existing method in NSString that would help...

Comment: @itgiawa Then perhaps in the future you can post more specific questions so that you don't waste the time of people who read your posts.